# Plot mass spectra of particle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
eta_c, psi, Omegastar, Omega
2.9839, 3.0969, 3.788, 3.712
\end{filecontents*}
```

I plotted the above mass of particle with Mathematica, which was shown following picture. Shell we plot it with latex easily?
[image]

Comment: You can look into TikZ and pgf plots to make plots like this.  But I'm not seeing how your file contents becomes the graph you've shown (the x-axis, but also the thickness of the bars).

Comment: Are there similarly example for this with latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.